# How to get an ocra application to be accepted by antiviruses

Tags: ruby, windows, exe, ocra

Alright, so judging by the title (if you practice Ruby), you should know what Ocra is. If you don't, here's a brief explanation:

Ocra is a command added to the command prompt in order to convert ruby programs to executable. So .rb to .exe.

In order for one to convert a ruby program to executable, they would type in the command prompt:

```
cd <locationOfFile>
ocra rubyProgram.rb
```

and then ocra would run the program and when that's done, it runs some scripts which completes the program. Then afterwards the executable version of the program would be in the same directory as the original ruby version and the same name.

So recently I noticed that my antiviruses are removing the program from my computer telling me it's a bloodhound. It's getting really annoying and I'm getting tired of having to use ocra over and over again just to remake a program.

I have two antiviruses: McAffee and Symnatec; so that means double the security. What can I change so that my antiviruses ignore the program?

Comment: Well, for one, two antivirus programs does *not* mean double the security, it means double the confusion. Installing multiple antivirus programs is highly discouraged and is likely to cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

Tell them to ignore/exclude the directory that the .exe is being built into.